# How to get the last occurrance of all items on a column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
item_id |    date    | cat |
----------------------------
   0    | 2020-01-01 |  A  |
   0    | 2020-02-01 |  B  |
   1    | 2020-04-01 |  A  |
   2    | 2020-02-01 |  C  |
   2    | 2021-01-01 |  B  |
```

So, I need to get the last category (column cat), that means that the result dataframe would be the following:

```
item_id | cat |
---------------
   0    |  B  |
   1    |  A  |
   2    |  B  |
```

I know I could sort the values by the date and then iterate over the itens, but that would be too much consuming. Is there another method on pandas to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` after `sort_values`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('item_id', keep='last')
   item_id        date cat
1        0  2020-02-01   B
2        1  2020-04-01   A
4        2  2021-01-01   B
```

Comment by @mozway:

> Sorting is O(n*logn)

```
>>> df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date']).groupby(df['item_id'], sort=False).idxmax()]

   item_id        date cat
1        0  2020-02-01   B
2        1  2020-04-01   A
4        2  2021-01-01   B
```

Comment: Sorting is `O(n*logn)`, use `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date']).groupby(df['item_id'], sort=False).idxmax()]` ;)

Comment: `idxmax` doesn't work on string, `sort_values` works on both :-P I'm kidding :-)

Comment: Yes it does! `df.loc[df['date'].astype('string').groupby(df['item_id'], sort=False).idxmax()]` or `df.loc[df.convert_dtypes().groupby('item_id', sort=False)['date'].idxmax()]` :p